# RethinkDB: Querying a nested optional boolean field

Tags: rethinkdb

My RethinkDB 1.16.2-1 on CentOS 7 "store" database has a "products" table which has a "models" array. I want to return the product ID and all models that contain the "isCatalogPick" boolean and omit models that do not have it, like this:

```
{
    "id":  "mid-200" ,
    "models": [
    {
        "isCatalogPick": true ,
        "ssp": 20.95 ,
        "weight": 0.07
    } ,
    {
        "isCatalogPick": true ,
        "ssp": 22.95 ,
        "weight": 0.13
    }
    ]
} {
    "id":  "msc-000" ,
    "models": [
    {
        "ssp": 39.95 ,
        "isCatalogPick": true ,
        "weight": 0.17
    }
    ]
}
```

My query:

```
r.db("store").table("products").pluck("id", "models").filter(
  r.row("models")("isCatalogPick").contains(true)
)
```

is also returning models without 'isCatalogPick' presumably because I am using contains():

```
{
    "id":  "mid-200" ,
    "models": [
    {
        "ssp": 14.95 ,
        "weight": 0.24
    } ,
    {
        "ssp": 17.95 ,
        "weight": 0.08
    } ,
    {
        "isCatalogPick": true ,
        "ssp": 20.95 ,
        "weight": 0.07
    } ,
    {
        "ssp": 22.95 ,
        "weight": 0.13
    }
    ]
} {
    "id":  "msc-000" ,
    "models": [
    {
        "ssp": 39.95 ,
        "isCatalogPick": true ,
        "weight": 0.17
    }
    ]
}
```

You would think that replacing "contains()" with "eq()" in the query would fix this but it returns no results.

My question is, how would I achieve this? Not essential, but if you can take the time to explain why the following queries also don't work, I think it will be educational to all:

```
r.db("store").table("products").pluck("id", "models").filter(
  r.row("models")("isCatalogPick").eq(true)
)

r.db("store").table("products").pluck("id", "models").filter(
  r.row("models").hasFields("isCatalogPick")
)

r.db("store").table("products").pluck("id", "models").filter(
  r.row("models").filter(function (c) {return c("isCatalogPick").eq(true)})
)

r.db("store").table("products").pluck("id", "models").filter( 
 function(c) { 
   return c.hasFields({'models': {'isCatalogPick': true}})
 }   
)

r.db("store").table("products").pluck("id", "models").concatMap(r.row('models')).filter(function(m) {
  return m.hasFields("isCatalogPick")
})

r.db("store").table("products").map( function (doc) {
  return {images: doc("id"), models: doc("models")}
}).filter(
  r.row("models").filter(function(c){
  return c("isCatalogPick").eq(true)
})
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could filter twice, once to remove the models and once to remove the products with no models left:

```
r.db("store").table("products").pluck("id", "models").merge({
  models: r.row('models').filter(function(m){ return m("isCatalogPick") })
}).filter(
  r.row("models").isEmpty().not()
)
```

You could also use `concatMap` to splat the models out:

```
r.db("store").table("products").concatMap(function(p){
  return p('models').merge({product_id: p('id')})
}).filter(r.row("isCatalogPick"))
```

Comment: Thank you. The first one (although more complex to me) is lightly more performant (~400ms vs ~450ms). Could you tell me why the following doesn't work? It seems to be the most intuitive solution. 

r.db("store").table("products").pluck("id", "models").filter(
  r.row("models")("isCatalogPick").eq(true)
)

Comment: `r.row("models")("isCatalogPick")` is an array of booleans and is not equal to true.

Comment: I understand. What about this one (last one I promise):
r.db("store").table("products").pluck("id", "models").filter(
  r.row("models").hasFields("isCatalogPick")
)

Comment: `r.row("models").hasFields("isCatalogPick")` returns an array, which is converted to bool and discarded because it is passed to `filter`.